# Why was Muhammad Ali Jinnah once called "Kafir e Azam"?

Tags: pakistan, history

Why was Muhammad Ali Jinnah, the Quaid e Azam of Pakistan, once called "Kafir e Azam"?

Comment: This question could use some context to show that it is relevant. Who called him that way and at what occasion? Kafir ("unbeliever") is a pretty serious insult for a founder of an Islamic republic, so context is important.

Comment: It's also important to know who called him this because depending on the person who made the statement, the reasoning could be quite different. Without this information it's difficult to know how to answer the question because the possible reasons are speculative and essentially infinite.

Comment: To most Muslims, calling someone who claims to be a Muslim a "kafir" is a *major* thing, not done without serious considerations of the totality of the situation as well as the likely backlash.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Still... isn't that a strictly religious thing? (i.e. not really politics)

Answer (score 5):

The Daily Times published an [opinion piece](https://dailytimes.com.pk/96685/is-jinnah-really-our-founding-father/) which recounted the story:

> The 1973 Constitution was amended in 1974 to declare an entire sect as being outside Islam, this sect being the Ahmedis. From 1937 to 1944, the pro-Congress Majlis-e-Ahrar-ul-Islam and other religious groups constantly pressurised Jinnah to declare Ahmedis as non-Muslims and throw them out of the Muslim League. Jinnah not only wisely resisted the pressure but also declared any such move as nothing less than a conspiracy to divide Muslims along sectarian lines. For this he was abused and attacked as Kafir-e-Azam...

The 1974 constitutional amendment declared Ahmedis as being outside Islam. Jinnah was being pressured to remove them from the Muslim League. He did not, which led to him being called Kafir-e Azam

Answer (score 3):

Jinnah, the first Leader of Pakistan, is given the honorary title "Quaid e Azam" or, roughly, "Great Leader". However Jinnah had had a Western education. He spoke fluent English, but little Urdu or even Gujarati (his parents were Gujaratis). He was a Muslim, but not an Islamist. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_Ali_Jinnah)

Kafir is a derogatory term for one who does not follow Islam. So changing "Quaid e Azam" to "Kafir e Azam" is an insult that targets Jinnah's westernised and non-Islamist attitudes.

This is straightforward political rudeness, probably intended to provoke.

Comment: Kafir (Arabic: كافر) is NOT a derogatory term. It's meaning ''unbeliever'' or someone who is a non-Muslim. Wanted to clear that since there's this misconceptions in the west.

Comment: When applied by one Muslim to another, it is insulting. It does not show respect, hence it is derogatory. It can be used in a neutral way, but this is not the intent here.

Answer (score 3):

There were [a number of Muslims](https://www.pakistantoday.com.pk/2013/12/21/mr-jinnahs-muslim-opponents/) who were opposed of the concept of formation of a separate land for Subcontinental Muslims (aka Pakistan) as they had their respective agendas and explanations. These are some people who were holding on to the title of **Maulana**s, and who never had any definite aim in their political philosophy which could be proven by the fact that except one or two, almost all of them migrated to Pakistan after partition.

[Maulana Mazhar Ali Azhar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazhar_Ali_Azhar) was one of them. This guy gave Muhammad Ali Jinnah this derogatory title.

[image]

According to [this link](https://tribune.com.pk/story/104683/jinnah-and-the-religious-right/):

> ... when Jinnah was spearheading the movement for Pakistan,
>   ... the Majlis-i-Ahrar ..., were vociferous opponents of
>   the concept of Pakistan. On March 3, 1940, the working committee of
>   the Majlis-i-Ahrar met in Delhi and reportedly passed a resolution
>   disapproving the Pakistan plan and in some subsequent speeches, the
>   Ahrar leaders reportedly dubbed Pakistan as ‘**palidistan**’. **Maulana
>   Mazhar Ali Azhar**, an Ahrar leader, appealed to the people not to be
>   misled by the slogans for Pakistan and, on other occasions, even
>   referred to Jinnah as **Kafir-i-Azam**.

According to the [Court Inquiry Report](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punjab_Disturbances_Court_of_Inquiry#Causes) for [Lahore riot in 1953](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1953_Lahore_riots), **Maulana Mazhar Ali Azhar** was one of the firebrands, which means, their post-partition agenda was to instigate anarchy in Pakistan.

Here is a page from the report:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"Kafir-e-Azam" is part of a phrase, and if you look at the complete sentence, then the reason for the name becomes clear. The complete phrase is used in connection with Jinnah's marriage to a non-Muslim woman.

This offensive couplet from Ali Azhar's poetry was used as the political slogan of his Ahrar movement against the Muslim League:

> Ik Kafira ke wastay Islam ko chhorra
> Ye Quaid-e-Azam hai ya Kafir-e-Azam

Literally translated, it implies that Mr Jinnah renounced Islam for an ‘infidel woman’, and asks whether he is "Quaid-e-Azam" (a great leader) or "Kafir-e-Azam" (a great infidel).

[Source](https://www.google.com/amp/s/m.thewire.in/article/books/ruttie-jinnah-interfaith-marriage-history/amp)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).